# Number of participants in Mturk?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm an absolute newbie in Mturk,and I'm definitely not a person who understands smth in programming. thus,I would appreciate a lot a simple answer on my question saying which button and where I should press(this is an upper limit of my computer skills).

the question is the following one:I want 200 people to participate in my survey. I want 1 pseron to answer on my survey just 1 time. where should I set those requirements? should I put the number 200 here:Number of assignments per HIT or there will be some other space where I will specify the number of my participants?

thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the **MaxAssignments** option of CreateHIT operation.
Here is the attached image for the developers guide
[image]

It says each worker can complete a HIT only once, so multiple assignments are guaranteed to be completed by multiple workers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have seen workers try to complete my HITs more than once, even though there not meant to see the HIT again. Here are some workarounds to prevent this form happening.

1. Republish the same HIT. Workers can access an identical HIT if it's published under a different name.
2. You can add a qualification for every worker that has already taken your survey. Even without programming, this is fairly simple. You can download a list of your workers, add the qualification on the spreadsheet for all of them, and then upload the spreadsheet into MTurk. When you set up your HIT, you can add this qualification. In this case, you would add: (Name of your qualification) Has Not Been Granted.

Good luck.